# Particle accelerator adapted to transport humans

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, particle-accelerators

Would it be possible to create a human transport system that uses the same principles as a particle accelerator?

So if you had a vacuum tube that could fit a 2 m diameter metallic sphere/pod that carries a human (with, say, a total mass with human, seat, luggage etc., 500 kg), what would be the most energy efficient or practical way to levitate the pod in the tube and then also propel it?

I thought about making the pod positive charged (like an H+ ion in the Linac2 at CERN's LHC) by making it a capacitor, then creating an opposite charge on the tube to keep the pod elevated in the middle and then using an electric field to propel it.

But maybe it'd be better to use magnetism to do the same thing or a combination of both electrical and magnetism?

What energies would be required to accomplish this if I wanted to travel from NYC to LA in 1 hr. That's a distance of 4000 km.

Comment: Something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperloop)?

Comment: Yes, it's called a [maglev train](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maglev).

Comment: Symmetry: The Hyperloop uses air to levitate the pod, not electric or magnetic fields. John Rennie: I'm familiar with how Maglev trains work. The problem I proposed is quite different. I'm interested in the physics and electric and magnetic field equations and values one would need given the parameters I provided.

Comment: So, a system that imparts 7 TeV of kinetic energy to the would-be traveler...?

Answer (score 0):

to be viable, any such scheme would need to be more economical than jumbo jet transport, which is hard to beat for cost-effectiveness. in addition, a jet can fly from any airport to any other, but a magnetic tube train requires a tube connecting any two stations- so a tube network will always be less flexible in terms of service. Finally, note that one tube can only serve one train at a time on a given route, whereas airplanes can be stacked at different altitudes so they can either follow parallel paths or cross over each other's paths without interference.

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of all that. I'm interested in the physics of such a project. Not whether this is a viable business.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is a physics site, so any aspects of practical engineering is off-topic. So then we can just assume a perfect vacuum in the tube, and that the tube is manufactured with any necessary precision, and that we coat it with superconductors. The magnetic pressure is $B^2/2\mu_0$, so if we distribute the weight over area $A$ we need $B = \sqrt{2\mu_0 mg/A}$ magnetic field from the capsule to keep it floating (in this case, 0.06 T - not too bad). You can do it with Lenz law over aluminum of course, but then there will be electric resistance.

The time to travel distance $d$ at constant acceleration/deceleration is $(1/2)a(t/2)^2=d/2$, or $t=2\sqrt{d/a}$. The limit on propulsion is just how much acceleration humans can handle. If we say it is about $5g$, then for $d=4000$ km it is 571 seconds. About 10 minutes.

Since everything is frictionless and impermeable to magnetic fields by assumption all the energy can be returned to capacitors or other storage for re-use: this is a fully reversible system. Some slight potential energy difference may exist due to the different distances to Earth's rotation axis, but that can clearly be managed.

Of course, building such a system is an entirely another matter.